# How do I add an owned device to a user using the Microsoft Graph SDK?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm building an application in C# and I want to add an owned device to a user using the Microsoft Graph SDK.  This is how I've added a user to group

```
await client.Groups[groupId].Members.References.Request().AddAsync(user);
```

I'm wondering if something similiar can be done to add a device to a user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
await client.Devices[deviceId].RegisteredOwners.References.Request().AddAsync(user);
```

can be used to add a device to a user.